# Trisecant lines to curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$: a reference request

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, projective-geometry

I'm starting to study the geometry of the locus of trisecant lines to a space curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}^3$. The main references, cited in almost all the papers, regarding the specific calculations of invariants of the locus of trisecant lines, quadrisecant lines etc. seem to be

1. L. Gruson - Ch. Peskine, *Courbes de l'espace projectif: varietes de secantes*
2. P.Y. Le Barz, *Formules multisecantes pour les courbes gauches quelconques, in
   Ennumerative geometry and classical algebraic geometry*

I'm not very familiar with the French, so anybody know references in which I can find the calculations and contents of these two papers in English?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your native language? If it is a neo-latin one (as Italian or Spanish) my suggestion is to put some effort in learning a little French. It will be not too difficult to reach a level sufficient to read mathematical papers.

Comment: I'd like to endorse Francesco Polizzi's comments in greater generality - you can get rather far by using Google translate plus some knowledge of mathematical French terms (fascieaux = sheaf, corps = field, [etc](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~kwlan/documents/french-glossary.pdf)). I mention this in case there are no positive responses to your query, and apologize for not having something more constructive to contribute.